# Azure encoding job error in Stage: GenerateOutputMediaMetadata

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, .net-core, cloud, azure-media-services

For the past two days I have been trying to run a media encoding job in Azure and I can't figure out why it fails.

Here is my workflow:

- I upload a file that has a GUID as the name in a storage container.
- I generate a sas uri and provide it as a JobInputHttp.
- The transform uses the `BuiltInStandardEncoderPreset` -> `AACGoodQualityAudio`

Every time the job fails at like 50% with the error:

> ErrorProcessingTask An error has occurred. Stage:
>   GenerateOutputMediaMetadata. Code: System.ArgumentNullException.

I am on .NET Core and using the latest version of `Microsoft.Azure.Management.Media` (2.0.4). Does anyone know why this error happens and how can I fix it?

My code follows the same practice as in https://github.com/Azure-Samples/media-services-v3-dotnet-quickstarts/blob/master/AMSV3Quickstarts/EncodeAndStreamFiles/Program.cs

Comment: Our logs indicate a few failed jobs in West Europe - presume these are the relevant ones? Asking our dev team to take a look. Thanks

Comment: @AnilMurching Yes the account is in west europe, some failed jobs are due to me testing different scenarios, I am only interested in the jobs that failed with the error described above. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that you have created a Transform with a custom preset, and not the built-in AACGoodQualityAudio preset - is that correct?

For that Transform, you would need to modify the filenamePattern to include an extension, either explicitly

```
"filenamePattern": "{Basename}.mp4"
```

or implicitly

```
"filenamePattern": "{Basename}{Extension}"
```

Thanks

Comment: Well at first I tried with that custom preset but then I changed to the built in AACGoodQualityAudio and was still getting the same error. I am going to try adding the extension and get back at you. Thanks a lot

Comment: Turns out even though I changed the preset to the default one, I forgot to change the transform name too.. The solution works, thanks again.